# How does Joseph Stiglitz and Greenwald explain why markets with imperfect information fail to have a pareto efficient equilibrium?

Tags: pareto-efficiency, asymmetric-information

How does Joseph Stiglitz and Greenwald explain why markets with imperfect information fail to have a pareto efficient equilibrium? What premises do they use to come to that conclusion?

For example, they write:

> "This suggests ... that if the government has no more information available to it than private firms ... it cannot make a Pareto improvement. This conclusion, however, is wrong. Taxes on goods or wages ... may change the extent of signaling"

But I don't see a logical (non-mathematical) explanation for their conclusion here. How can taxes change signaling to increase economic welfare?

Comment: Is this the paper: http://socsci2.ucsd.edu/~aronatas/project/academic/Stiglitz%20Greenwald.pdf

Comment: Hey I think it is! I know it was written in 1986 with Greenwald. It must be it!